# How to Use Method from a Class that has been Passed in as a Variable

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I have JLabels in multiple JFrames, and all of them serve the purpose of being a status indicator. In the class *Controller*, I have a method that changes the JLabel in the given JFrame. **My question is that how do I reference the JFrame as a variable?**

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Controller {
    public static class Status {
        public static void vPrint(JFrame frame, String text) {
            JLabel label = frame.getConsoleLabel();
            label.setText(text)
        }
    }
}
```

So when I call it in the JFrame:
`Controller.Status.vPrint(this, "Set the JLabel Text.");`

All of the JFrames have the method `getConsoleLabel()`

The problem is that when I call it, it says: `cannot find symbol: method` and I think the cause is that the variable frame isn't referenced.

Any solutions?

Comment: *"I have JLabels in multiple JFrames.."*  1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556) 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are extending the `JFrame` to some Class but trying to invoke the `getConsoleLabel()` on the super class `JFrame` which doesn't have such method. So yes, you can't invoke `getConsoleLabel` on instance of `JFrame` no matter to which type the reference of this instance is referring to. Rather declare your own frame `MyFrame extends JFrame` which has implementation of `getConsoleLabel()` change the signature of `vPrint` with parameter type `MyFrame` and pass the required instance of type `MyFrame` to `vPrint`.

And DON'T USE MULTIPLE `JFrame` as Andrew has suggested. Follow the linked answer by him.

Answer (score 0):

Well you specialized `JFrames`s have `getConsoleLabel()` method.

You have two solutions:

1. Create an interface with `getConsoleLabel()` and make all of your `JFrame`s implement that interface. And change the signature of `vPrint` to accept an instance of your interface instead of `JFrame`.
2. Create an class such as `LabledFrame extends JFrame` which has `getConsoleLabel()` and extend all of your `JFrame`s from that, and change the `vPrint` to accept an instance of `LabledFrame` instead of `JFrame`.